# Solve $y''+(y')^2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My idea is to set $v=y'$, then I get that
$$
y'' = v \frac{dv}{dy}.
$$
Hence the equation reads
$$
v\frac{dv}{dy}+v^2y=0\Leftrightarrow v\left(\frac{dv}{dy}+vy\right)=0
$$
and hence
$$
v = 0\text{ or }\frac{dv}{dy}+vy=0.
$$

For the second option, I get separate variables to get the equation
$$
\int \frac{1}{v}\, dv = -\int y\, dy
$$
which gives
$$
v = C e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}
$$

Is this correct and how can I proceed?

I am just wondering how to get the solution(s) which are given [here (see Example 2)](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html) which is
$$
\begin{cases}y=C,\\\frac{y^2}{3}-2Cy=2x+C^*\end{cases}
$$

Of course, from $v=0$, I also get that $y=C$ for some constant $C$ is a solution. But what about the other solution?

Comment: Also $y=y(x)=0, \forall x \in (a,b)$ it is a solution.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I see that from $v=y'=0$, one solution is $y=C$ for some constant C is a solution.

Comment: It is, but unfortunately you are out of luck (or in luck, depending on how you look at it) because when you apply separation of variables to that last equation (the next logical step, you get that $y = \sqrt{2}\operatorname{erfi}^{-1}(C_1x + C_2)$, where erfi is the imaginary error function and we have taken its inverse.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/nonlineareq/nonlineareq.html  - - How does one get the solution given here (EXAMPLE 2 is the equation here)

Comment: @Rhjg When I solve the differential equations I check if the function identically null satisfies the initial differential equation. Afterwards I proceed as you did and at the end I see if there are any extensions of the solutions of the equation.

Comment: You read the example 2 wrong, which admittedly is not very difficult to do. The pixel mass in the exponent is not a $2$, it is a $3$, in some edgy font, $$y''+(y')^3y=0\implies -(y')^{-1}+\frac12y^2=C.$$ Then you also get the rational expression instead of an exponential.

Answer (score 2):

Solve instead
$$x'=c_1\,e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}$$ which will give
$$x=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erfi}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{c_1}+c_2$$ Do not try to make it explicit in $y$.